# How to convert geth genesis to parity genesis?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, genesis

In order to convert `geth` genesis to `parity` genesis I have guided into following link: [github.com/keorn/parity-spec](http://github.com/keorn/parity-spec). I followed the explained usage.

When I try to run: `cargo run -- example-geth.json` I am faced with following error:

```
error: An unknown error occurred

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

-

```
*[master][~/parity-spec]$ sudo cargo run --verbose

error: could not execute process `rustc -vV` (never executed)

Caused by:
  No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

[Q] How could I prevent this error from happening? or is there any other way to convert `geth` genesis to `parity` genesis?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: What are the extra details it outputs when you run it with `--verbose`?

Comment: What does `--verbose` say? Could you add the whole log? It's working for me, just tested.

Comment: @5chdn Sorry just added.

Comment: Are you running it from inside the same directory as `example-geth.json`? (i.e. The directory created by `git clone`?)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Yes sir I am.

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming. I'll leave it to the Rust experts to comment further :-)

Comment: What's the output of `rustc -Vv` ?

Comment: @5chdn Ah that is the problem, I feel like stupid. `rustc` haven't installed. The problem is probably will be  fixed I after I install it from: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.

Comment: I didn't know you can run cargo without rust :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error: could not execute process `rustc -vV` (never executed)

Install rust https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/ :)

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

Comment: If my Genesis file starts with `"config": {"homesteadBlock": 0},` , https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/378fb95285c91d40bf6f1b9f4bf2acd2 , it sees JSON file as invalid, but I guess that line is not much important.

Comment: `"homesteadBlock" : 0` translates to `"homesteadTransision" : "0x00"` in parity json.